# How to use pug with sails.js

Tags: sails.js, pug

One would thing this would be a fairly straight-forward process as sails states that if the templating engine is supported by consolidate you can switch it out.  Their instructions are listed at https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/views/view-engines using .swig as an example.

I have configured my config/views.js per listed instructions.  However when doing a `sails lift` it just renders my pug template as it was typed so it's not compiling anything.

config/views.js

```
module.exports.views = {
  extension: 'pug',
  genRenderFn: function() {
    let cons = require('consolidate');
    return cons.pug;
  },

  layout: false

};
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think it should be `engine: "pug"`

Comment: Yes, `engine: "pug"` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Generate your Sails project with jade:
`sails new your-project --template=jade`

Navigate to your project views folder: 
`cd your-project/views`

change .jade to .pug:

```
for file in *.jade; do mv $file `basename $file .jade`.pug; done
npm i --save pug
```

Open config/views.js 
 change `engine: "jade"` to say `engine: "pug"`

Save & Lift